# gmail Received-SPF: neutral

Tags: spf

When I try to send an email with php to my gmail address, I receive the email but there is a problem with spf. It says Received-SPF: neutral

But here the spf record seems good http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3atr1.mybasiccrm.com&run=toolpage

So what's the problem, thank you all!

Here is the details:

```
    Delivered-To: myself@gmail.com
    Received: by 10.200.34.84 with SMTP id p20csp368076qtp;
    Thu, 30 Jun 2016 07:02:31 -0700 (PDT)
    X-Received: by 10.195.11.163 with SMTP id ej3mr15637555wjd.130.1467295351319;
    Thu, 30 Jun 2016 07:02:31 -0700 (PDT)
    Return-Path: <tr1mybasiccrm@tr8.mybasiccrm.com>
    Received: from tr8.mybasiccrm.com ([89.19.23.154])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id h8si4088654wjq.8.2016.06.30.07.02.30
    for <myself@gmail.com>;
    Thu, 30 Jun 2016 07:02:30 -0700 (PDT)
    Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 89.19.23.154 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of tr1mybasiccrm@tr8.mybasiccrm.com) client-ip=89.19.23.154;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=neutral (google.com: 89.19.23.154 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of tr1mybasiccrm@tr8.mybasiccrm.com) smtp.mailfrom=tr1mybasiccrm@tr8.mybasiccrm.com
    Received: from tr1mybasiccrm by tr8.mybasiccrm.com with local (Exim 4.87)
    (envelope-from <tr1mybasiccrm@tr8.mybasiccrm.com>)
    id 1bIcY0-0005Ml-HU
    for myself@gmail.com; Thu, 30 Jun 2016 17:02:28 +0300
    To: myself@gmail.com
```

Comment: Looks like you added an SPF record to your `ty8` change it to this, `v=spf1 a ~all` you went a little overkill with your record, which requires adding processing on the receiving mail server. Also I think your PTR records don't match your hostname, send an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SPF record for `tr1` is correct, but you sent from `tr8`, which doesn't have an SPF record and thus gets a neutral result.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you have deployed an spf record for the subdomain tr1.mybasiccrm.com and the mail was sent from tr8.mybasiccrm.com.

If you want to avoid that issue you could remove the record from the subdomains and add it at the domain level to mybasiccrm.com.

I understand that in that way all the subdomains of mybasiccrm.com would be covered by the domain policy.

Comment: This is incorrect. SPF records for any given domain will not be considered when querying against any of its subdomains. This makes sense, any subdomain will require its own RRs (MX TXT etc) and is essentialy a discrete domain.

Comment: Hello sir. Thanks for comments. Do you have the source, please?

Comment: No problem... RFC7208 (4.1. Arguments) qualifies <domain> as the domain portion of the "MAIL FROM" or "HELO" identity. That said you can (with care) publish wildcard RRs in DNS, see (3.5.  Wildcard Records)